# jmap -histo error message "Not enough memory"

Tags: jmap

When trying the command `jmap -histo`  in servers, getting an error message "not enough memory to process this command". I know that taking `-histo` will give a small file. But its just giving the error message.

Can anyone please suggest me in taking the `-histo`(memory utilization of all jobs).